# "Modules are Outdated" Error

Tags: magento-2.0

I get this error when I create a new module:

```
"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:

Sangeeta_Octan data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1";i:1;s:1781:"#0
```

I searched on google and found no solution other than reinstalling Magento. Such as:

> version has been changed from "2.0.0.0" to "2.0.0" during development,
>   so update tool can't recognize that "2.0.0.0" <= "2.0.0". Please,
>   re-install your application from scratch to get latest version. `

Do I have any options apart from reinstalling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Change the **setup_version** of your module (Sangeeta_Octan) in
   `app/code/Sangeeta/Octan/etc/module.xml`. Try a different version
   name like `setup_version="2.0.1"` or `setup_version="3.0.0"`
2. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. If that doesn't work, disable your module by changing your module name in `app/etc/config.php`from `Sangeeta_Octan => 1` to `Sangeeta_Octan => 0`. Then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I hope below solution also solve your problem.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112293/mysql-error-and-possible-duplicates-running-bin-magento-setupupgrade-after-rena/112299#112299

Answer (score 7):

in mysql find the table `setup_module`   It will have 3 fields.  Find the `NULL` values in `data_version` & have them match the `schema_version`

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, you can access your magento database and look at the table `setup_module`
You will see a list of all installed modules and you can manually set the schema/data version numbers here.

Comment: I have to do this quite a lot, not sure why it gets confused

Answer (score 0):

Delete the offending rows from the `setup_module` table (if they are there) and run the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` from your Magento 2 root directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens because of something wrong while running "bin/magento setup:upgrade"  and the data_version  in Module versions registry is null.  It is loaded from DB,  We can just proceed by manually changing it in db.

Go db via php myadmin and check "setup_module" table, the
data_version which are mentioned "null".

```
Login to Mysql database => then update table setup_module of the "data_version" column same as "schema_version"
```